# Как установить в input неудаляемый текст?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Проще всего обьяснить суть задачи на скрине:

На изображении есть поле в котором bit.ly уже предустановлено как значение (а может и нет) и его удалить нельзя. Все что я могу сделать в этом поле это редактировать значение после слеша. Как сделать такое решение?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы поставьте значение bit.ly  как текст, а после него только вставьте инпут где пользователь что то будет набирать....

Comment: @Arsen ну да че то я не посмотрел исходный код. они действительно так и сделали. Это был муляж)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Здесь можешь посмотреть как он работает

http://jsfiddle.net/shvr9afd/1/

```
<input type="text" value="Эй ты! А ну иди сюда! " style="width: 500px;" class="test">

<script>
var $inp = $(".test"), prevVal = '',
    reference = "Эй ты! А ну иди сюда! ";

function change (val) {
    var ind = val.indexOf(reference);

    if (ind !== 0) {
        $inp.prop("value", prevVal || reference);
    } else {
        prevVal = val;
    }
}

$inp.on("input", function () {
    var val = $(this).prop("value");
    change(val);
});
</script>
```

Comment: Спасибо! Ваше решение очень помогло, без лишних муляжей как говориться:)